# mp3 file type uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, frameworks

I have to upload a mp3 file type with codeigniter upload library.
I use the following code.

But it doesn't work.

The class controller code:

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|mp3';
            $config['max_size']             = 0;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
}
?>
```

When the file type is jpg or like that, this code correctly works and the jpg file is uploaded.
But when I try to upload an mp3 file, the file doesn't upload.
And not any error shows up.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check your php.ini and make sure you max upload and post sizes are larger than the mp3 you're trying to upload. Your code looks fine, I highly suspect the problem is in your php.ini

Answer (score 2):

add this code on `mime.php`  (`application/config/mimes.php`) file.
This is right answer :

OLD:

> 'mp3'  =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3','audio/mp3')

NEW:

> 'mp3'  =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg','audio/mpeg3','audio/mp3','application/octet-stream')

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Add in your file mimes.php (application/config/mimes.php) the 'application/octet-stream' in each array of mime you want to do upload, example;

```
OLD: 'mp3'  =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3')
MEW: 'mp3'  =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3', 'application/octet-stream')
```